# Format datetime conversion show default datetime

Tags: gridview, yii

I have a Cgridview date output as  `2013-03-25 13:30:00`

but i want in this output as `Monday 25 March 2013 1:30 pm`

I have already used this to get

```
array('name'=>'Appointment','value'=>  'date("j F Y,g:i a",  strtotime("$data->Appointment"))'),
```

But its showing `1 January 1970,1:00 am`

what i have missed here? Please Help.

Comment: What value is `strtotime("$data->Appointment")` returning?

Comment: if i use `strtotime("$data->Appointment")` return nothing.Grid is blank and if i use $data->Appointment its showing `2013-03-25 13:30:00`

Comment: Show us your `date.timezone` PHP setting

Comment: here is the Php setting `date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta`

Comment: Do you have any Yii timeZone setting (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#timeZone-detail) ? And make a `var_dump` on `$data->Appointment`, then show us result. Finally did you try with http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter ?

Comment: No I didnt have any Yii timezone setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why `strtotime` doesn't work here, but with Yii you can use :

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateTimeParser

e.g. :

```
array(
  'name'=>'Appointment',
  'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("EEEE d MMMM y hh:mm:ss a", CDateTimeParser::parse($data->Appointment, "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"))'
),
```

If you want to use this date format elsewhere, you can define a getter in your model.

Comment: Soju i tried your solution it gives the current date-time.The var_dump is `string(33) "Tuesday 26 March 2013 04:16:30 PM"  `

Comment: Please make a var_dump on $data->Appointment, not on my value.

Comment: I got the answer `$data->Appointment` returning nothing i changed to `$data['Appointment']`

Comment: You should delete your question since it is not really describing the real problem

Answer (score -1):

Try this it may solve your problem

```
array('name'=>'Appointment','value'=>'date("j F Y,g:i a",$data->Appointment)'),
```

Comment: No, value is a PHP expression that will be evaluated for every data cell : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataColumn#value-detail

Comment: @RohitSubedi the result is the same `1 January 1970,1:00 am`

Answer (score -1):

Please Try the following pattern. It works for me.

```
array(
'name'=>'added_date',
'value'=>'date("j F Y,g:i a",strtotime($data->added_date))',
),
```

Did u tried in this way?